# Publishing a VB.net single page application over IIS to user over VPN users

Tags: .net, iis, server, vpn, lan

Can anyone help me to publish a VB.net single page application to production as I am trying to publish this single page web application over IIS and purpose is other users over the VPN can use this web application. I have created this application with visual studio .net 3.5 and connected to SQL server for data exchange. The application works only for me as on localhost but not able to accessed by other users over the VPN / LAN.

Regards,Anil

Comment: You might get started from site bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background and then talk to your network administrators to see what else (firewalls/routers) you need to configure.

Comment: Can I publish the web app on windows 10 enterprise copy or would I  need windows server OS ?